# Asked to open a BOA account and then transfer to other accounts via cash withdrawal. Is this some kind of scam?

Tags: banking, scams

I set up a chase account in my name, $19,500 was deposited. Which I took out in cash and deposited in other accounts for her. This account was then closed. Before that though, I got a phone call from chase saying the funds deposited ha been recalled. Now the same thing is going on with a BOA account.

My personal account has not been touched but I am wondering if I am being scammed or used for an illegal purpose.

I have also done three MoneyGram s for her to Africa, Florida and California.

Please help

Comment: There are a lot of red flags here.  I'd suggest contacting your lawyer ASAP.

Comment: While the details of your particular situation may not match the original poster in the other question I've linked, the resolution will be the same. Since you have already begun following through on the requests of the people who are scamming you, it is vital that you talk to a lawyer immediately.

Comment: Absolutely a scam, and double-recommend talking with a lawyer immediately - otherwise you could be personally liable for wire fraud, money laundering, and god knows what else. And the amount of money involved could easily escalate it to multiple felonies - seriously, do nothing else for this person and immediately talk to a criminal attorney first, keep all documentation, and have your lawyer advise you on how to contact the police. This is bad - get professional help to fix it now before it's too late.

Answer (score 4):

See past answers tagged scam. Yes, you are almost certainly in legal trouble; at best it sounds like you're being used as a mule to move illegal funds.